# Using byte array in MediaElement wmv source instead of wmv path

Tags: c#, arrays, mediaelement, wmv

I have a wmv file. In xaml source file ı am using this wmv file as a Media element. Just ı want use displaying with byte array instead of  this wmv file path. How can ı do it ?

Here is the xaml part

```
<MediaElement Name="VideoControl" Source= "Content\\Images\\PutBaggage.wmv"  Width="902" Height="650" Canvas.Left="63" Canvas.Top="282">
    <MediaElement.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MediaElement.Loaded">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <MediaTimeline Source="Content\\Images\\PutBaggage.wmv" Storyboard.TargetName="VideoControl" RepeatBehavior="Forever" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </MediaElement.Triggers>
</MediaElement>
```

and here is the from wmv to byte conversation :

```
protected override void BasePage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    String path = @"Content\\Images\\PutBaggage.wmv";
    FileStream filer = File.OpenRead(path);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(filer);
    byte[] file = br.ReadBytes(99999999);

    base.BasePage_Loaded(sender, e);
}
```